# Web Deploy publish/package validating error: Missing or Invalid property value for $(MsDeployServiceUrl)

Tags: webdeploy

I use VS2019 to precompile my web site then publish to the web server. If I directly press the Publish button, the web published successfully. But if I press preview link then start preview button, after the files appear. I excluded the web.config file and press the publish button, then the visual studio error list shows 2 errors as follow:
1.Web Deploy publish/package validating error: Missing or Invalid property value for $(MsDeployServiceUrl)
2.Target GenerateGlobalPublishSetting Failed

[image: publish]

I tried to reinstall the VS2019 on my computer and it still showed the same errors.
I don't know this is the VS2019 problems or the server site problems.

Can someone help me? thanks!

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem. I just upgraded from VS 2019 16.5.x to 16.6.1 within the last day or so, so I'm suspicious of the upgrade. This may not be a factor, but my project is an old Web Site Project built using WebForms and the .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: Also having this issue. Like @Theophilus, it's an old Web Site project. I can get a valid preview which shows appropriate adds/updates, but then when I hit 'publish', it fails with the errors in OP's question.